# Comparing against multiple values in the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

I want to find all statuses such that the value is always `NO`.  THAT MEANS I WANT OUTPUT IS 2 ONLY BECAUSE ITS ALL VALUE IS NO.
HOW  I GET THE VALUE THROUGH SQL QUERY

```
 STATUS_ID  STATUS
   1        YES
   1        YES
   2        NO
   2        NO
   2        NO
   3        YES
   3        NO
```

Comment: **Don't shout.....**

Comment: Renamed the first `STATUS` column to `STATUS_ID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a basic conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT STATUS_ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY STATUS_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS <> 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```